# If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the zeroes of $p(x) =x^2- px +q = 0$

Tags: polynomials

Find $\alpha^2 + \beta^2$ and $\alpha^3 + \beta^3$.

Comment: What you have tried??

Comment: Hello, and welcome to math.SE. Please take a look at [how to ask a question](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to format mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: what is the meaning of $.x2$?

Comment: I think he means ${x}^{2}$

Comment: Such things [have a name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickson_polynomials#Properties).

Answer (score 4):

We have, $$x^2-px+q=0 $$ $$\implies \alpha+\beta=\frac{-(-p)}{1}=p$$ & $$\alpha\beta=\frac{q}{1}=q$$ Now, we have $$\alpha^2+\beta^2=(\alpha+\beta)^2-2\alpha\beta$$
$$=(p)^2-2q=p^2-2q$$

$$\bbox[5px, border:2px solid #C0A000]{\color{red}{\alpha^2+\beta^2=p^2-2q}}$$
& $$\alpha^3+\beta^3=(\alpha+\beta)(\alpha^2+\beta^2-\alpha\beta)$$
$$=(p)(p^2-2q-q)=p^3-3pq$$ $$\bbox[5px, border:2px solid #C0A000]{\color{red}{\alpha^3+\beta^3=p^3-3pq}}$$

Answer (score 3):

$\bf{My\; Solution::}$ Given $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are two roots of $x^2-px+q=0$

So $$\displaystyle \alpha+\beta = p$$ and $$\alpha \cdot \beta = q$$

Now $$\alpha^3+\beta^3 = \left(\alpha+\beta\right)^3-3\alpha \cdot \beta \left(\alpha+\beta\right) = p^3-3pq$$

and $$\alpha^2+\beta^2 = \left(\alpha+\beta\right)^2-2\alpha \cdot \beta = p^2-2q$$

Answer (score 2):

For convenience, we reverse the sign of $q$, without loss of generality.
$$x^2-px-q$$ is the characteristic equation of the recurrence
$$x_{n+2}=px_{n+1}+qx_n,$$
that has the general solution

$$a\alpha^n+b\beta^n.$$

With $a=b=1$,

$$x_0=2,\\
x_1=\alpha+\beta=p,\\
x_2=\alpha^2+\beta^2=px_1+qx_0=p^2+2q,\\
x_3=\alpha^3+\beta^3=px_2+qx_1=p(p^2+2q)+pq=p^3+3pq,\\
x_4=\alpha^4+\beta^4=px_3+qx_2=p(p^3+3pq)+(p^2+2q)q=p^3+4p^2q+2q^2,\\
x_5=\alpha^5+\beta^5=px_4+qx_3=p(p^3+4p^2q+2q^2)+(p^3+3pq)q=p^4+5p^3q+5pq^2,\\\cdots
$$

The general formula is closely related to the development of $(p+q)^n$.

Answer (score 0):

You have $p=\alpha+\beta$ and $q=\alpha \beta$

Now $p(\alpha)+p(\beta)=0$

Expanding the two expressions gives $\alpha^2+\beta^2-p(\alpha+\beta)+2q=\alpha^2+\beta^2-p^2+2q=0$

Note also that $\alpha p(\alpha)+\beta p(\beta) =0$ and this gives $$(\alpha^3+\beta^3)-p(\alpha^2+\beta^2)+q(\alpha+\beta)=0$$And this can be used to compute $\alpha^3+\beta^3$ from what is already known.

With a little thought this can be generalised to a range of other situations.